# JavaScript eventlistener onclick call another function after animation

Tags: javascript, callback, onclick, event-listener

How to implement a callback function on an onclick evenlistener on an object?

Samplecode:

```
object.addEventListener("click", clickFunction);
```

What I want to achieve is that after the function clickFunction  is finished, another function get called.

clickfunction:

```
var clickFunction = function() {
   //Do something for 5 seconds
}
```

Comment: why not just put the other function call at the end of the click handler?

Comment: Why doesn't this work? var clickFunction = function() {
   nextFunction()
}

Comment: Yes, I thought of this. But the function clickFunction adds a CSS class to the object to trigger an animation with a duration of 5s

Comment: I would use `$().trigger('myEvent')` from the callback, then from your function just use `$(document).on('myEvent',function(){ //do stuff });`

Comment: Without using jQuery please.

Comment: You can add a listener that will launch a callback at the end of your animation like :
`el.addEventListener("transitionend", doSomethingWhenMyAnimationIsFinished, true)` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delay then execute the next function:

```
var clickFunction = function() {


   setTimeOut(function() {
          thatOtherFunction();
    }, 5000);   // after 5 seconds
};
```

Comment: Was thinking of that, but I didn't find this a good solution because I work with animation. I find it a bit dirty